# Dynamic calculate values from inputs

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've a script calculates my dynimic buy form.
Everything works fine but when I add quantity input script takes only first value. I want to it takes every next value from "value" (each). I will be glad for help.

```
$(function() {
    $("#sumuj").click(function() {
        var add = 0;
        var add2 = 0;
        $(".netto").each(function() {add += Number($(this).val()) * $(".value").val();});
        $(".brutto").each(function() {add2 += Number($(this).val()) * $(".value").val();});
        add = add.toFixed(2);
        add2 = add2.toFixed(2);
    $("#price").val(add);
    $("#pricevat").val(add2);
    });
});
```

Done:

```
$(function() {
    $("#sumuj").click(function() {
        var add = 0;
        var add2 = 0;
        $(".netto").each(function() {add += Number($(this).val()) * Number($(this).parent().find('.value').val());});
        $(".brutto").each(function() {add += Number($(this).val()) * Number($(this).parent().find('.value').val());});
        add = add.toFixed(2);
        add2 = add2.toFixed(2);
    $("#price").val(add);
    $("#pricevat").val(add2);
    });
});
```

Thx for help/

Comment: jsfiddle and corresponding HTML would be helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your script is incorrect : if you select all the value ( $(".value") ), and I believe you have different line of products, you will have strange equation  (you multiply every value together ?? )

And please add a link of your page.

Comment: I will glad for help with that script

Comment: Can you please paste the full page generated on jsfiddle ? We can't read easily your code. Here you sent us the php file not compiled, not very interesting ...

Comment: Maybe that question will be better: How get every next "value" class input? in jquery? $(".netto").each(function() {add += Number($(this).val()) * $(".[every-next]value").val();});

Comment: You have to adapt your HTML for simplify your JS. In your case, I would put something like :
$(".line").each(function() {resultLine = parseFloat($('.price').val()) * parseFloat($(".quantity").val());})